# Filter NA accros subset of columns defined as numeric name

Tags: r, pivot, tidyverse

I am trying to filter all records that contain systematic NA across a subset of numerical columns.

Here is a toy example.

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(
    year = c(2001, 2002, 2003, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2001),
    rank = c(12, 25, 65, NA, NA, NA, NA),
    category = c("a", "a", "b", "c", "c", "c", NA),
    other = c("x", "y", "x", "y", "x", "y", "x")
)

df %>%
    pivot_wider(names_from = year, values_from =  rank) %>%
    filter(.cols = c(2001:2003),
           .fns = ~ !is.na(.x))
```

This code doesn't work, it cannot recognize the columns `2001:2003` - What is the correct way to basically remove the third record by filtering all NA for columns 2001, 2002, 2003.
The columns range needs to be specified as a range similarly as I do 2001:2003.

The record "c" should be filtered out, but not the record were all columns are NA (last one in the toy example)

This is the error I am getting :

> Error: Problem with `filter()` input `..1`. x Input `..1` is named. ℹ
> This usually means that you've used `=` instead of `==`. ℹ Did you
> mean `.cols == c(2001:2003)`?

Comment: You want to remove category c, as all 2001 to 2003 are NAs?

Comment: All records that contain NA for the columns 2011:2003, appears to be the record `c` but it can be any other

Comment: Why not just `df %>% drop_na() %>% pivot_wider(...)`?

Comment: because drop_na will drop all NA for all columns not for the 2001:2003 - I will refine the example

Comment: The data I am dealing with is in the wide format and this is how I should keep them - `df` is a helper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter by columns. Use `across`

```
df %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = year, values_from =  rank) %>%
  filter(rowSums(!across(`2001`:`2003`, is.na)) > 0L)
```

Ouput

```
# A tibble: 3 x 5
  category other `2001` `2002` `2003`
  <chr>    <chr>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1 a        x         12     NA     NA
2 a        y         NA     25     NA
3 b        x         NA     NA     65
```

Answer (score 0):

By my knowledge, you cannot filter by columns. You can only select by columns. Here is what I would do.

```
df %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = year, values_from =  rank) %>%
  pivot_longer(2:4) %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  filter(!any(is.na(value)))
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be better to `filter` before doing the `pivot_wider`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>%
    group_by(category, other) %>% 
    filter(any(!is.na(rank))) %>% 
    ungroup %>%
    pivot_wider(names_from = year, values_from = rank)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 x 5
#  category other `2001` `2002` `2003`
#  <chr>    <chr>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#1 a        x         12     NA     NA
#2 a        y         NA     25     NA
#3 b        x         NA     NA     65
```

Comment: Indeed but the data I am working with are coming in the wide-format - I used a toy example to come to the format of my data to explain the problem.